How to separate data in multiple departments in Autodesk platform service
Multiple departments of a large company handle different CAD files and I need to store those files separately based on the department. Departments won't be able to access other department's files. There is only one subscription for the company.
By going through the documentations, I found following two approaches to store files.

Create separate OssBucket for a each department - Can we do this securely?
Create separate application for each department - Is there any maximum limit for creating application in one subscription?

Could you please let me know what is the best approach to store these files.
I tried to store files which are owned by different departments of a company securely

From my perspective, creating separate applications for each department might be a better option. This approach logically separates the work and simplifies maintenance, reducing potential confusion.
Additionally, as of now, there isn't a theoretical or logical limit to the number of applications you can create under a single subscription. However, it's important to note that the subscription is associated with a single email address or account owner.
